# first steps in Angular and Laravel - re-compiling failed

Tags: angularjs

I want to make changes in a new script. This is based on laravel and angularjs. With both in have no experience.

So it seems that this work completely different as i normally work with standalone php and js files. I read that i have to re-compile the codes.

So i have setup a local XAMP Server and to the following think, but it seems that every step failed and I don't know why?

```
   Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp
# cd htdocs

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs
# cd cmseditor

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# cd sourcecode

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
# npm install

> node-sass@4.9.3 install c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modules\node
-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.3\w
in32-x64-64_binding.node

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_mo
dules\phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantom
js-2.1.1-windows.zip
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting zip contents
Removing c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\li
b\phantom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.
1.1-windows.zip-extract-1542948580758\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows -> c:\xampp\htdocs
\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_mo
dules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe

> circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modu
les\circular-json
> echo ''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m
, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''

''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[
1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modules\
node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\node_modules\node-sass\vend
or\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)

added 1390 packages from 1902 contributors and audited 30413 packages in 700.658
s
found 5 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
#
```

the second think i try was

```
  Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp
# cd htdocs

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs
# cd cmseditor

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# cd sourcecode

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
# cd..

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# npm run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-23T04_54_22_3
19Z-debug.log

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# cd sourcecode

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
# npm run build

> cli@0.0.0 build c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
> ng build --source-map=false --prod --source-map --common-chunk=false --deploy-
url=client/

Der Befehl "ng" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cli@0.0.0 build: `ng build --source-map=false --prod --source-map --com
mon-chunk=false --deploy-url=client/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cli@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-23T04_54_48_9
68Z-debug.log

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
#
```

and at least i try this

```
   Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp
# cd htdocs

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs
# cd cmseditor

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# cd sourcecode

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
# cd..

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# npm run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fibu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-23T04_54_22_3
19Z-debug.log

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# cd sourcecode


Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp
# cd htdocs

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs
# cd cmseditor

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# gulp c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode
[06:02:38] No gulpfile found

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# gulp
[06:02:48] No gulpfile found

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# gulp c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\sourcecode\
[06:03:26] No gulpfile found

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
# gulp c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor\
[06:04:43] No gulpfile found

fibu@FIBUSERVER c:\xampp\htdocs\cmseditor
#
```

Thanks for helping and explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the server-setup.

After uninstall angularjs and reinstall all commands work successful.